# <ctrl>+<alt>+<up_arrow> interpreted as <Home> when recording VS Code key binding

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings, vscode-keybinding

I am attempting to remap the key binding for `scrollPageUp` and `scrollPageDown` from `<alt>+<page_up>` and `<alt>+<page_down>` to `<ctrl>+<alt>+<up_arrow>` and `<ctrl>+<alt>+<down_arrow>`, respectively.

However, when in the 'key binding recorder' (where it says `Press desired key combination and then press ENTER`), `<ctrl>+<alt>+<up_arrow>` and `<ctrl>+<alt>+<down_arrow>` are interpreted as `<Home>` and `<End>`, respectively.

How do I set up my key bindings as desired?

Comment: Is this specific to VSCode? Some cheap keyboards are physically incapable of differentiating between some key combo's.

Comment: I don't know if it's specific to VSCode. I am using a Logitech K810 keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

Maebe your shortcut settings are duplicated this options. See in docs how you lock this settings and change this, if you can.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).